# Have a background image with a transparent colour

Tags: css

I’d like to be able to have a background image with a transparent colour covering the image. But when I try to put

```
background-image: url(mylocation);
background-color: darkgray;
opacity: 0.5;
```

inside the body {} tags, the image shows, but not the colour, and everything else is transparent. I’m pretty sure that everything else is transparent because they’re all child section of the body, but how would I fix this, so that it’s the way I’d like it to be?

Thanks!

Comment: How does the body of your question relate to the title? They seem to be 2 very different things?

Comment: Oops, that's a title from something else..

Comment: Do either of these answers help? Or are you still stuck?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
body{
  background:url('Image url');
  opacity:0.5;
}

#container{
  background:transparent:
}
//=====================contain all tags
```

HTML design:

```
<body>
 <div id="container">
 </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

The background color is a fallback if the image can't be displayed, not a background for the image. Also be aware that `opacity` applies to the entire contents of the element, not just the background.

Try

```
html {
    background:url('Image url'); 
}


body {
    /*Use RGBA to get transparent color*/
    background-color:rgba(100,100,100,0.5);
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin:0;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ky6my3z3/1/)

Though this may be a better option:

```
body
{
    background-image: url(http://placehold.it/200x200/ff0000/ffffff&text=BG+Image);
}


body:before
{
    display:block;
    opacity:0.5;
    background-color:darkgrey;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    content:"";
    z-index:-1;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ky6my3z3/)