# Have a transparent when hover each images(not background)

Tags: css

I have this code

```
<div class="photo">
<img src="images.jpg">
<div class="text">Its transparent</div>
</div>
```

I have tried this **css**

```
.text{
    opacity:0.8;
    background-color:#ccc;
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    z-index:1000;
}
```

also this

```
.text{
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28) none repeat scroll 0 0;
    color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    top: -240px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%
}
```

I want to the text above in *images*(not a background) with transparent background. I does have a transparent but it doesnt cover the whole images. I have tried this but doesnt apply to me.

[Allow a div to cover the whole page instead of the area within the container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18588835/allow-a-div-to-cover-the-whole-page-instead-of-the-area-within-the-container)

[Background images: how to fill whole div if image is small and vice versa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779577/background-images-how-to-fill-whole-div-if-image-is-small-and-vice-versa)

[Have a background image with a transparent colour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26112586/have-a-background-image-with-a-transparent-colour)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set `.photo { position: relative; }` then use `position: absolute;` to `.text`

```
div.photo .text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
}
```

Try on: https://jsfiddle.net/mmouze3n/1/

### Edit 1 -

Adding a blur overlay by `:before`

```
div.photo .text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 26px;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 1;
  webkit-transition: .3s;
  transition: .3s;
}
div.photo:hover .text { font-size: 100px; color: #000; }

div.photo:before {
  display: inline-block;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  background-color:#ccc;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  webkit-transition: .3s;
  transition: .3s;
}
div.photo:hover:before {
  opacity:0.8;
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mmouze3n/2/

Comment: but how can I make the text not affected by transparent?

Comment: @PureRhymerOrganization So... you want the background ***image*** transparent but not the text right?

Comment: Yes only the *image*

Comment: Kindly checkout my revised answer